# Moving the caret in webkit-gtk

Tags: webkit, gtk, caret

With the "enable-caret-browsing" option set on a WebkitWebView, is it possible to programatically move the caret with respect to lines of text as they are appear on screen? For example, move to end of visual line rather than move to end of DOM node.

This behavior is accessible through keyboard navigation (e.g. the End key goes to end of visual line), but couldn't find anything in the API for this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try emitting the [`move-cursor`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-move-cursor) signal?

```
gboolean result;
g_signal_emit_by_name(view, "move-cursor", GTK_MOVEMENT_DISPLAY_LINE_ENDS, +1, &result);
```

I'm curious if this works.

Comment: This gives an assert: CRITICAL **: gboolean webkit_web_view_real_move_cursor(WebKitWebView*, GtkMovementStep, gint): assertion `step == GTK_MOVEMENT_VISUAL_POSITIONS || step == GTK_MOVEMENT_DISPLAY_LINES || step == GTK_MOVEMENT_PAGES || step == GTK_MOVEMENT_BUFFER_ENDS' failed. 

Interestingly, changing it to use GTK_MOVEMENT_DISPLAY_LINES scrolls the page down rather than moving the caret.

Comment: Hmm, looks like they haven't implemented `GTK_MOVEMENT_DISPLAY_LINE_ENDS` yet. Perhaps take a look inside the Webkit-GTK sources to see what's going on?

Comment: I have done so, and the function connected to "move-cursor" indeed appears to do only scrolling. What I have not yet been able to find is where pressing the motion keys (arrow keys, home/end, etc) is moving the caret when enable-caret-browsing is enabled.

Comment: I agree, it's difficult to find out where it is. I got as far as `WebCore/platform/gtk/GtkInputMethodFilter.cpp` but am none the wiser. Perhaps ask on the WebKit development mailing list?